# Well ordered set, Binary relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, well-orders

[image]

My attempt: A is well ordered, hence every subset of A has a minimal element;

Since ⟨A,≤1⟩ is WO, it is isomorphic to an ordinal β, which is finite. But α is an ordinal as well. So we can define a function g: β-> α;

If we define the function f to map the min element a1 of an arbitrary subset of A,say A1, to f(a1), then for every a' in A1 we have that a1<=a', because of the order preserving.

Also f(a1)<=f(a').
If β and α are order isomorphic, then for every b in A (or after my assumption we can say β as well) we have f(b)=g(b).

And since A has an initial element a1, then this a1 will satisfy f(a1)<g(a1).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have to start with an arbitrary non-empty subset $B \subseteq {^A}\alpha$ and show it has a minimal element for the defined order.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Well, I think that A1 is such a set, or I am wrong?

Comment: $A_1$ is a subset of $A$, the domain, not of the set you're trying to show to be a well-order.

Comment: BTW you claim in the beginning that the well-order $A$ is isomorphic to a finite ordinal $\beta$. This is nonsense of course.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So If I just pick another arbitrary subset of the ordinal alpha, say B, then B is in Rng and I will just apply the same approach. Or this will be a mistake?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I meant that <A,<A>  is isomorphic to β .Sorry for that.

Comment: $\langle A, <_A\rangle$ is isomorphic to some unique ordinal $\beta$ yes. But $\beta$ can be infinite, and probably is.

Comment: See what [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation) quotes for ordinal exponentiation: the order of the coordinates should be reversed, in the sense that we compare values first and then domain. Your exercise is plainly wrong.And if $A$ were finite, ${^A}\alpha$ is just a finite linearly ordered set so trivially well-ordered.

Answer (score 4):

Either I'm misreading the question or the following is a counterexample. Let $A=\omega$ with the usual ordering and let $\alpha=2$. For each natural number $n$, define $f_n:\omega\to2$ by
$$
f_n(k)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }k<n\\1&\text{if }k\geq n. \end{cases}
$$
Then $f_0\succ f_1\succ f_2\succ\dots$, so $\preceq$ is not a well-ordering.

Comment: <A,<A> should be finite.

Comment: @Tiki your problem states "well-ordered set", not finite. $\alpha$ is finite in the assumptions.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right, in the problem it should be added finite well ordered and then the problem will not be trivial.

Comment: @Tiki then the problem **is** trivial, unless $\alpha$ is allowed to be infinite:  a finite lo set is well-ordered, and there is nothing to prove.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Well then we can say that α is allowed to be infinite.